# Valgrind error appears when using getc() in a while loop

Tags: c

I have an assignment, whereas I'm trying to print characters from a file. A problem appears, when I'm trying to iterate through the file using a while-loop. It seems as if I increase FILE ptr value outside the while loop and then use the getc() function, no error appears, but as soon as I pass it into the loop, something happens after the first round of iteration. Can anyone please explain, why the error might appear?

```
/* Prints the given file as text on the screen.
 * Only printable characters are shown. Non-printable characters are printed
 * as '?'. <filename> parameter is the name of the file.
 * 
 * Returns the number of characters read
 */

int textdump(const char *filename){

    FILE *textdump = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!textdump) {
        return -1;
    }

    int getchar, eval, count = 0;
    /*The following few lines work, but as soon as I try to increase textdump inside the while loop, I get a valgrind error*/
    //getchar = getc(textdump);
    //textdump++;
    //getchar = getc(textdump); //this still doesn't give a Valgrind error..
    while ((getchar = getc(textdump)) != EOF) { //after first round the valgrind error appears?!
        eval = isprint(getchar);
        if (eval == 0){
            printf("?");
            textdump++;
            count++;
        }
        else 
            printf("%c", getchar);

            textdump++; //can this get out of bounds? shouldn't because end of file should appear before that...
            count++;

    }
    fclose(textdump);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why do you increment it? There is no reason to do it. Remove all `textdump++;` and then, the code will work

Comment: I guess from your comment, that the getc() moves the pointer forward automatically, thus there's no need for textdump++; ?!

Comment: Yes. There is absolutely no reason to do `textdump++`

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'm new to I/O streams and kind of assumed that pointers have to be moved manually as in our previous assignments..

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the file pointer which will lead to undefined behavior.

```
textdump++;
```

Pointer arthmetic is always done based on the size of the object the pointer is pointing to in this case incrementing the file pointer doesn't do what you expect it to.

`getc(fp)` will make sure that the file-pointer advances to the next character.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that seems strange to me:

**1:** Why increment `textdump` ?
check: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/

> Returns the character currently pointed by the internal file position
>   indicator of the specified stream. The internal file position
>   indicator is then advanced to the next character.

**2:** Your `if/else` shoud look like that I think:

```
if (eval == 0)
    printf("?");
else 
    printf("%c", getchar);
```

or just

```
if (isprint(getchar))
    printf("%c", getchar);
else 
    printf("?");
```

There is a double incrementation if `eval == 0` is true in your code. Not the exact problem you were looking for but a problem anyway

Answer (score 0):

The `textdump` pointer is a pointer at a library-internal structure of type `FILE`, which in turn represents which file on disk you have opened, contains buffer management information, and so on.

It is *not* somehow a direct pointer into the actual file's data, on disk. The `FILE` structure instance is the same for the entire interaction, you really shouldn't be increasing it. You get the `FILE` pointer from `fopen()`, pass it to all functions that need to deal with the file, and then finally to `fclose()`. All the time the pointer value will be exactly the same.